# Why do I get these error when trying to build my project with JUCE and CPP?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, juce

**So this is the code to which visual studio points at when building (with error).**

```
namespace juce
{

//==============================================================================
AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::Parameter (const String& parameterID,
                                                    const String& parameterName,
                                                    const String& labelText,
                                                    NormalisableRange<float> valueRange,
                                                    float defaultParameterValue,
                                                    std::function<String (float)> valueToTextFunction,
                                                    std::function<float (const String&)> textToValueFunction,
                                                    bool isMetaParameter,
                                                    bool isAutomatableParameter,
                                                    bool isDiscrete,
                                                    AudioProcessorParameter::Category parameterCategory,
                                                    bool isBoolean)
    : AudioParameterFloat (parameterID,
                           parameterName,
                           valueRange,
                           defaultParameterValue,
                           labelText,
                           parameterCategory,
                           valueToTextFunction == nullptr ? std::function<String (float v, int)>()
                                                          : [valueToTextFunction] (float v, int) { return valueToTextFunction (v); },
                           std::move (textToValueFunction)),
      unsnappedDefault (valueRange.convertTo0to1 (defaultParameterValue)),
      metaParameter (isMetaParameter),
      automatable (isAutomatableParameter),
      discrete (isDiscrete),
      boolean (isBoolean)
{
}
```

**Here is the other function which gives error**

```
juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout
SaundAudioProcessor::createParameterLayout()
{
    juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout layout;


    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("Low Cut Freq", "Low Cut Freq",
        juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 20.f));

    juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout layout;
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("High Cut Freq", "High Cut Freq",
        juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 20000.f));

    juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout layout;
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("Peak", "Peak",
        juce::NormalisableRange<float>(20.f, 20000.f, 1.f, 1.f), 750.f));

    juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout layout;
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("Peak Gain", "Peak Gain",
        juce::NormalisableRange<float>(-24.f, 24.f, 0.5f, 1.f), 0.0f));

    juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout layout;
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterFloat>("Peak Quality", "Peak Quality",
        juce::NormalisableRange<float>(0.1f, 10.f, 0.05f, 1.f), 1.f));



    juce::StringArray stringArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4;i++) {
        juce::String str;
        str << (12 + i * 22);
        str << "db/Oct";
        stringArray.add(str);
    }

    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterChoice>("LowCut Slope", "LowCut Slope", stringArray, 0)); 
    layout.add(std::make_unique<juce::AudioParameterChoice>("HighCut Slope", "HighCut Slope", stringArray, 0));



    return layout;

}
```

And the some of the errors which Visual Studio gives.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C2084   function 'juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::Parameter(const juce::String &,const juce::String &,const juce::String &,juce::NormalisableRange,float,std::function<juce::String (float)>,std::function<float (const juce::String &)>,bool,bool,bool,juce::AudioProcessorParameter::Category,bool)' already has a body (compiling source file ....\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)   Saund_SharedCode    E:!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp   42

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C2011   'juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterAdapter': 'class' type redefinition (compiling source file ....\Source\PluginEditor.cpp) Saund_SharedCode    E:!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp   79

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   C2086   'void (__cdecl *const `juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::AudioProcessorValueTreeState'::`2'::PushBackVisitor::`vftable'[4])(void)': redefinition (compiling source file ....\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp) Saund_SharedCode    E:!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp   229

**Here are the errors from output**

*

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Saund_SharedCode, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>PluginProcessor.cpp
1>PluginEditor.cpp
1>include_juce_core.cpp
1>include_juce_data_structures.cpp
1>include_juce_events.cpp
1>include_juce_graphics.cpp
1>include_juce_gui_extra.cpp
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(42,5): error C2084: function 'juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::Parameter(const juce::String &,const juce::String &,const juce::String &,juce::NormalisableRange<float>,float,std::function<juce::String (float)>,std::function<float (const juce::String &)>,bool,bool,bool,juce::AudioProcessorParameter::Category,bool)' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(30): message : see previous definition of '{ctor}' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(59,73): error C2084: function 'float juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::getDefaultValue(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(59): message : see previous definition of 'getDefaultValue' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(60,73): error C2084: function 'int juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::getNumSteps(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(60): message : see previous definition of 'getNumSteps' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(62,73): error C2084: function 'bool juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::isMetaParameter(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(62): message : see previous definition of 'isMetaParameter' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(63,73): error C2084: function 'bool juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::isAutomatable(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(63): message : see previous definition of 'isAutomatable' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(64,73): error C2084: function 'bool juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::isDiscrete(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(64): message : see previous definition of 'isDiscrete' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(65,73): error C2084: function 'bool juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::isBoolean(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(65): message : see previous definition of 'isBoolean' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(68,1): error C2084: function 'void juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::valueChanged(float)' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(67): message : see previous definition of 'valueChanged' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(69): warning C4390: ';': empty controlled statement found; is this the intent? (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(79,56): error C2011: 'juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterAdapter': 'class' type redefinition (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.h(367): message : see declaration of 'juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterAdapter' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(227,5): error C2084: function 'juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::AudioProcessorValueTreeState(juce::AudioProcessor &,juce::UndoManager *,const juce::Identifier &,juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout)' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(223): message : see previous definition of '{ctor}' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(229,12): error C2086: 'void (__cdecl *const `juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::AudioProcessorValueTreeState'::`2'::PushBackVisitor::`vftable'[4])(void)': redefinition (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(229): message : see declaration of 'const `public: __cdecl juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::AudioProcessorValueTreeState(juce::AudioProcessor &,juce::UndoManager *,juce::Identifier const &,juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout)'::`2'::PushBackVisitor::`vftable'' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(231,34): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginEditor.cpp)
1>INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe'
1>    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(42,5): error C2084: function 'juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::Parameter(const juce::String &,const juce::String &,const juce::String &,juce::NormalisableRange<float>,float,std::function<juce::String (float)>,std::function<float (const juce::String &)>,bool,bool,bool,juce::AudioProcessorParameter::Category,bool)' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(30): message : see previous definition of '{ctor}' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(59,73): error C2084: function 'float juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::getDefaultValue(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(59): message : see previous definition of 'getDefaultValue' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(60,73): error C2084: function 'int juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::getNumSteps(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(60): message : see previous definition of 'getNumSteps' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(62,73): error C2084: function 'bool juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::isMetaParameter(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(62): message : see previous definition of 'isMetaParameter' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(63,73): error C2084: function 'bool juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::isAutomatable(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(63): message : see previous definition of 'isAutomatable' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(64,73): error C2084: function 'bool juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::isDiscrete(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(64): message : see previous definition of 'isDiscrete' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(65,73): error C2084: function 'bool juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::isBoolean(void) const' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(65): message : see previous definition of 'isBoolean' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(68,1): error C2084: function 'void juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::Parameter::valueChanged(float)' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(67): message : see previous definition of 'valueChanged' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(69): warning C4390: ';': empty controlled statement found; is this the intent? (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(79,56): error C2011: 'juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterAdapter': 'class' type redefinition (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.h(367): message : see declaration of 'juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterAdapter' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(227,5): error C2084: function 'juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::AudioProcessorValueTreeState(juce::AudioProcessor &,juce::UndoManager *,const juce::Identifier &,juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout)' already has a body (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(223): message : see previous definition of '{ctor}' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(229,12): error C2086: 'void (__cdecl *const `juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::AudioProcessorValueTreeState'::`2'::PushBackVisitor::`vftable'[4])(void)': redefinition (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(229): message : see declaration of 'const `public: __cdecl juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::AudioProcessorValueTreeState(juce::AudioProcessor &,juce::UndoManager *,juce::Identifier const &,juce::AudioProcessorValueTreeState::ParameterLayout)'::`2'::PushBackVisitor::`vftable'' (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>E:\!!!!Coding\JUCE\JUCE\modules\juce_audio_processors\utilities\juce_AudioProcessorValueTreeState.cpp(231,34): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation (compiling source file ..\..\Source\PluginProcessor.cpp)
1>INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.30.30705\bin\HostX64\x64\CL.exe'
1>    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>cl : command line error D8040: error creating or communicating with child process
1>Done building project "Saund_SharedCode.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
2>------ Build started: Project: Saund_StandalonePlugin, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(1087,5): error MSB6006: "link.exe" exited with code 1104.
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Saund.lib'
2>Done building project "Saund_StandalonePlugin.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

- 

Comment: Its better to copy the errors from the Output tab instead of the errors list.

Comment: I can't see from the code you provided but make sure you are not including any `.cpp` files

Comment: I added the errors from output. Why no .cpp files?

@drescherjm

Comment: `INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR` is a bug in the compiler. You may have to contact Microsoft and wait for them to fix that and perhaps use a different version of Visual Studio while you are waiting for the fix.

Comment: @Konjak He means don't `#include` .cpp files in other .cpp files. The error message you're getting is telling you that the function bodies are being defined more than once which means either the .cpp files are being `#include`d or you're defining the bodies out of line in a header file.